# html input textbox tag stored in a variable show it in angular template

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a variable that is assigned HTML text box tag.i want to display as text box and access its value

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-field-add',
  templateUrl: './field-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./field-add.component.css']
})
export class FieldAddComponent implements OnInit 
{
    public htmlTextBox ="<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='Field'  name='Field'>"
}
```

On The template I have placed the variable

```
{{ htmlTextBox }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular security Blocks dynamic rendering of HTML and other scripts. You need to bypass them using DOM Sanitizer.

DO below changes in your code :

```
// in your component.ts file

//import this 
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';


// in constructor create object 

constructor( 
...
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer

...
){

}

someMethod(){
 let htmlTextBox ="<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='Field'  name='Field'>"
 this.htmlData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlTextBox ); // this line bypasses angular security

}
```

and in HTML file ;

```
<!-- In Your html file-->
    <div [innerHtml]="htmlData">
    </div>
```

You can read more here  :  [Angular security](https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis)

Working example : [Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arsvz2)

Answer (score 1):

That is the way that you would display plain text in your div, like so

**Solution 1:**

```
<div class="blog-post">{{testhtml}}</div>
```

But that will write out text, not HTML.

For HTML, you will need to bind to the property

**Solution 2:**

```
<div class="blog-post" [innerHtml]="testhtml"></div>
```

Leaving out the square brackets would bind to the attribute, so you would need to interpolate again

**Solution 3:**

```
<div class="blog-post" innerHtml="{{testhtml}}"></div>
```

The property binding (Solution 2) is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

Try `innerHtml`:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlTextBox">
</div>
```